# Behavior of <?php echo date("H:i:s", 0);?>

Tags: php, date, datediff

I used :

```
<?php 
echo date("H:i:s", $var_time_diff);
?>
```

to construct a time between two dates.. and in my head it was
`$var_time_diff = 36000 = display 10:00:00 for 10 hours`.

But in fact

```
<?php echo date("H:i:s", 0);?>
```

display `01:00:00` and not `00:00:00`.

So we have

```
$date_a = "18:15:04";
$date_b = "23:15:04";
$diff = strtotime($date_b) - strtotime($date_a);
```

All is ok for the moment `$diff` is 5 hours but if we display date like this:

```
echo date("H:i:s", $diff);
```

it will be `"06:00:00"`.

So something wrong with my php config or it's a normal behavior for php function date?

Answer (score 5):

The `date()` function uses your current time zone. If you want to ignore your configured time zone, use `date_default_timezone_set()` or use `gmdate()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're in some timezone other than UTC.  Try:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("H:i:s",0) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but `date` outputs the current hour in your example, make a timestamp from your seconds first and it works. I'll be following this question for a deeper explanation though.

```
$date_a = "18:15:04";
$date_b = "23:15:04";
$diff = strtotime($date_b) - strtotime($date_a);
echo date("H:i:s", mktime(0,0,$diff));
```

edit: ah, so it adjusts to your current timezone, so does `mktime`, so the effect is negated.

Answer (score -1):

use mktime, and min 1 for hour @ $diff